# returnURL always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Working on login functionality right now and for some reason i continue to get returnURL as null. I have followed the answers from this [ASP.NET MVC Login ReturnUrl always NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827905/asp-net-mvc-login-returnurl-always-null) , yet have had no luck.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
```

Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Since your adding the url to `ViewBag`, you can use `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {`

Answer (score 0):

You should put it as a hidden field inside of the form instead.

Comment: Just tried removing the returnURL request from my beginform and tried "<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]" />" but still null.

Comment: Does the hidden input that is rendered have an empty value or is it losing the value when you post the form? I personally wouldn't ever touch the request object to get a value. You should have whatever page is rendering that value take that in as a param and then put it on a ViewModel.