# How to feed information to the filter context of the AuthorizeAttribute - HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, authorize-attribute

When my `AuthorizeAttribute` is called, it sends the page to login like it should.  But when login is completed, it goes out to home/index.  This is super annoying.  How can I keep that from happening?
Since the code path never goes into my controller, I don't have any control of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using forms authentication, when you access a page that requires authentication, ASP.NET will redirect you to the login page, passing in the ReturnUrl as a parameter.

So, all you need to do is use that parameter to return the user to the place it was before.

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string pass, string returnUrl)
{
   // code to authenticate user here...

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
     return Redirect(returnUrl);

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

You might also want to consider using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage

```
Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default URL.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=vs.110).aspx

Notice that calling this method will also issue the authentication cookie, that you might be already doing. So you have to check you are not doing this twice.

Edit: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206728/722778

Perhaps you are generating your form specifying a controller an action (e.g. Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account")?

In that case, try with only this in your view:

```
Html.BeginForm()
```

Or passing the ReturnUrl parameter yourselve:

```
Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })
```

Comment: The problem is that the Login function never receives the returnUrl when they are redirected and I cant figure out how to make sure it's passed.